# If-Then-Else Opening Word Document

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to create an If-Then-Else statement in MS Access VBA.
This statement is to open a specific word document but if the word document does not exist then open a different word document.

Below is the code I have and it works if I get rid of the else but that doesn't solve my problem because I need the else statement.

```
Dim appword As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim Path As String

Set appWord = GetObject(, "word.application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
   Set appWord = New Word.Application
   appWord.Visible = True
End If

If Value = "Excused" Then
   Path = "C:\...existing docx"
Else
   Path = "C:\...different docx"
End If

Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open(Path, , True)
```

Comment: I forgot to note that the else part will be opening a different word document not a entirely new word document.

Comment: Use the EDIT link under your Question to change the text of the question so that it is read correctly the first time people see it. Also explain HOW your current code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `appword.Documents.Add` to return a new Document.  You should also add an Error Handler when using `GetObject`.  You may also consider using `Len(Dir(Path))` to test if the file exists.

```
Dim appword As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim Path As String
On Error Resume Next
Set appword = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set appword = New Word.Application
    appword.Visible = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0

If Value = "Excused" Then
    Path = "C:\...existing docx"
    Set doc = appword.Documents.Open(Path, , True)
Else
    Set doc = appword.Documents.Add
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Validate the document exists and if not add a new document.

```
Sub T()
    Dim appword As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim Path As String

    Set appword = New Word.Application
        appword.Visible = True

    If Len(Dir("C:\...existing docx")) > 0 And Value = "Excused" Then
        Path = "C:\...existing docx"
        Set doc = appword.Documents.Open(Path, , True)
    Else
        Set doc = appword.Documents.Add
    End If
End Sub
```